# Image on a button

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I expect the same output for both of the scripts below.

But I don't get the image on the button when I execute **Script 1**. However, **Script 2** works well.

**Script 1**

```
from Tkinter import *
  class fe:
    def __init__(self,master):
      self.b=Button(master,justify = LEFT)
      photo=PhotoImage(file="mine32.gif")
      self.b.config(image=photo,width="10",height="10")
      self.b.pack(side=LEFT)
root = Tk()
front_end=fe(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Script 2**

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
b=Button(root,justify = LEFT)
photo=PhotoImage(file="mine32.gif")
b.config(image=photo,width="10",height="10")
b.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The only reference to the image object is a local variable. When `__init__` exits, the local variable is garbage collected so the image is destroyed. In the second example, because the image is created at the global level it never goes out of scope and is therefore never garbage collected.

To work around this, save a reference to the image. For example, instead of `photo` use `self.photo`.

Comment: I was stucked on the same thing, and your answer worked like a charm. Thank you @BryanOakley!

Comment: Can't get it to work, even when using "self.photo...". Can the difference be Python 3???

Comment: @rlinner: no, nothing has changed between python 2 and python 3 with respect to images.

Answer (score 1):

its work

```
x1=Button(root)
photo=PhotoImage(file="Re.png")
x1.config(image=photo,width="40",height="40",activebackground="black"
,bg="black", bd=0,command=sil)
x1.place(relx=1,x=5, y=-5, anchor=NE)
```

but this is useless

```
def r():
    x1=Button(root)
    photo=PhotoImage(file="Re.png")
    x1.config(image=photo,width="40",height="40",activebackground="black",
    bg="black", bd=0,command=sil)
    x1.place(relx=1,x=5, y=-5, anchor=NE)

r()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
logo = PhotoImage(file = 'mine32.gif')
small_logo = logo.subsample(5, 5)
self.b.config(image = small_logo , compound = LEFT )
```

Comment: why do you assign `photo` and then not use it?

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated answer, but this is the answer I was looking for when I first came here. Use this to resize the image before adding it to the button.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("path/to/image.png")
image = image.resize((25, 25), Image.ANTIALIAS)
self.reset_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
self.button = tk.Button(frame, image=self.reset_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

from tkinter import *

```
root= Tk()

btnPlay = Button(root)
btnPlay.config(image=imgPlay, width="30", height="30")
btnPlay.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```