# Using an image as a button in Python 3.5 Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, python-3.5

Using tkinter, how can I make a button that it is picture not text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image on a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297949/image-on-a-button)

Comment: There must be millions of examples on the internet, and this feature is widely documented. You should do a little research before asking a basic question like this.

Answer (score 3):

Some searching revealed [Image on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297949/image-on-a-button). It uses the `PhotoImage` function. To explain some code included in it:

```
from Tkinter import *                         # Import tkinter
root=Tk()                                     # Create an instance using Tk()
b=Button(root,justify = LEFT)                 # Create a button
photo=PhotoImage(file="mine32.gif")           # Give photo an image
b.config(image=photo,width="10",height="10")  # Configure the earlier instance to use the photo
b.pack(side=LEFT)                             # Pack up the button
root.mainloop()                               # Create everything
```