# How to view and unview a password in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a program (below) that creates an entry box that shows only '*' when you type in it and it creates a button next to the text box. I want the button to show what has been typed in the entry box while it is being pressed. I have tried to use `<Button-1>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>` but to no avail.

```
import tkinter as tk

def myFunc() :
    #Something#
    pass

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Password')
password = tk.Entry(root,  show = '*')
password.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
password_label = tk.Label(text = 'Password:')
password_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
button = tk.Button(text = '.', command = myFunc)
button.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

Comment: Use `<tkinter.Entry>.config(show="")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def show_stars(event):
    password.config(show="*")

def show_chars(event):
    password.config(show="")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Password")
password = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
password.grid(row=0, column=1)
password_label = tk.Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row = 0, column=0)
button = tk.Button(text="Show password")
button.grid(row=0, column=2)

button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", show_chars)
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", show_stars)
```

Using the bindings that @BryanOakley suggested

Comment: That works. Thank you. This is a bit of a tangent, but is it possible to display an image in a button instead of text?

Comment: @Manav yes you can. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4297949/11106801)

Comment: You could just reduce the use of two functions, by using `if`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Wouldn't that be slower (theoretically)? Also its easier to read and understand the code if it is split in 2 functions (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

Only if button is pressed it changes the text from * to the text entered.

```
import tkinter as tk

def myFunc():
    #Something#
    if password.cget("show")=="*":
        password.configure(show="")
    elif password.cget("show") =="":
        password.configure(show="*")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Password')
password = tk.Entry(root,  show = '*')
p = password
password.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
password_label = tk.Label(text = 'Password:')
password_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
button = tk.Button(text = '.', command = myFunc)
button.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
root.mainloop()
```